# How to get the address of a variable stated in C Macro?

Tags: c, macros, memcpy

I am new to C and am trying some macro statements. I have a line like this:

```
#define write_data(src, TYPE, VALUE ) (write_implement(src, sizeof(TYPE), &(VALUE)))
```

And in a later function, I would like to use `memcpy` to copy the `VALUE` in another memory zone. Like this:

```
void write_implement (void* src, int size_of_type, void* value)
{
    //whatever, just making the destination address from the source address
    void* dest = src + 4096;
    memcpy(dest, value, size_of_type);
}
```

The VALUE being passed in can be of any kind of data. That's why I am using void* to point to it and memcpy to copy the number of size of bytes.

But it doesn't work of course :)

This is how I call the function:

```
write_data(addr, int, i*3); // i is a whatever integer variable
```

GCC gives me this:

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

Does anyone have any idea how to find the address of the variable being passed in to the macro in order to allow me to make use of the address for copying?

The later part of the macro can be changed (the "write_implement" and the parameters but not the "write_data" parameters). And the implementation part is also free to change.

Comment: Where's the call to the macro that causes that error?

Comment: The problem is not happening in the code you have shown.  It's probably due to how the macro is used.  Can you show how you're using the macro?

Comment: Since the macro just replaces VALUE with i * 3, getting the address won't work

Comment: Sorry about missing the call :( It looks like: write(addr, int, i * 3);

Comment: Then is there any way to get the address of the i*3? :)

Comment: @Ken: Instead of posting in the comments, you can just edit your question - makes it a lot easier for us to read.

Comment: int a = i * 3; write_data(addr, int, a); ?

Comment: Question modified, Thanks!! (New to Stackoverflow)

Comment: @irrelephant: Then what if I pass a char type. Or even a typedef structure... My assignment sucks :(

Comment: Must the macro have those parameters?

Comment: Ar.. Sorry to irrelephant. I can somehow change to macro a little bit. The later part can be changed (the write_implement part and the parameters but not the previous "write_data" parameters). And the implementation part is also free to change.

Comment: @Ken: can you tell as what each of the macro parameters can/must be ?

Comment: #define write_data(src, TYPE, VALUE ) (write_implement(x, y, z)) 
The previous part is fixed and must be used. The later part which is the implementation part is free to change. (The x, y, z) But I think only the (&VALUE) is needed to change :) x and y are quite right aren't they?

Comment: @Ken: BTW, unless you have already allocated sufficient space after the address pointed to by src, your write_implement function is not going to work. You cannot just pull buffer addresses out of your^W thin air.

Comment: ok, and what is this macro supposed to do _exactly_ ?

Comment: @thkala: Thanks for your comment. I have the memory :) As I initialized them with memset before. (Not shown in the question)

Comment: It is to allow the caller to pass in a address, a data type and the value for me to write in the memory zone. Since type is not defined, I will use sizeof(TYPE) to get the bytes for memcpy. The remaining problem is the VALUE part..

Answer (score 5):

If your compiler supports C99 compound literals, you can do this:

```
#define write_data(src, TYPE, VALUE) write_implement(src, sizeof(TYPE), &(TYPE){ VALUE })
```

Comment: +1 C99 allows anonymising a lot of structures like this. Always very useful if you can use it.

Comment: GREAT!! Exactly what I want. Thanks!!

Comment: +1 for using compound literals. Just as additional remark, @Ken T, you should have your `value` parameter `void const*` and the compound literal also as `&(TYPE const){ (VALUE) }`. The `const` will help your optimizer, the paranthesis will avoid that commas in your `VALUE` expression will be misinterpreted as separating different initializers.

Comment: @Jens: I don't agree with the parentheses - commas would fail anyway because they would be treated as macro argument separators.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#define write_data(src, TYPE, VALUE ) { \
        TYPE xxxx##__LINE__ = (VALUE); \
        write_implement(src, sizeof(TYPE), &(xxxx##__LINE__)); \
    }
```

It uses a somewhat "random" variable to store the value, before passing its address.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand the macro, you get for the third parameter, `&(i * 3)`, which makes no sense. You can take the address of a variable, but not of an anonymous expression result.

If you want to pass a value in using `void*` to hold the type, then you'd better have an actual variable named to hold it.

```
int i = 5;
int j = i * 3;
write_data(addr, int, j);
```

I gotta say, though, to me calling the function directly is cleaner:

```
write_implementation(addr, sizeof(int), &j);
```

It's possible to do some C magic to make the macro call look the way you wanted, although I'd advise against it.

```
#define write_data(src,type,value) \
    {type t = (value); write_implementation(src, sizeof(type), &t);}

write_data(addr, int, i*3);
```

And, as an aside, a C++ template would allow you to use the result of an expression the way you wanted as well, and a bit prettier (the key is the const ref).

```
template <typename T>
write_impl(T& dest, const T& src)
{
    memcpy(&dest, &src, sizeof(T));
}

// 'int' is the default type of 5*3
int intResult;
write_impl(intResult, 5*3);

// 'double' is the default type of 5.1*4.7
double doubleResult;
write_impl(doubleResult, 5.1*4.7);

// otherwise, have to cast
long longResult
write_impl(longResult, (long)5*3);
```

Comment: ah, I suggested pretty much the same CPP black magic, though a few seconds later. Does this look like some semi-sadistic/semi-idiotic homework assignment to anyone else?

Comment: Your rewritten version of the macro doesn't actually use `value`.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I added it. The major restriction is that the macro parameters `src` and `value` could not be named `t`. Still comes with the caveat that I'd advise against doing it.